# Disable Hazelcast packaged configuration

Tags: hazelcast

When starting Hazelcast automatically falls back on the packaged / default config when it doesnt find the specified hazelcast.xml file.

The problem i have with this is that i'm running hazelcast in a docker containter with the config file mapped as a volume. However if something goes wrong with either the config file or the volume mapping Hazelcast happily starts without error, but is completely useless, because the default are not what we use in production.

Is there some way to make hazelcast fail if the configFile specified (`java  -Dhazelcast.config=/etc/hazelcast/hazelcast.xml -jar /usr/local/hazelcast.jar`)  is corrupt or missing?

Comment: The version specified correctly errors when the file is not found, that was problematic in a older version i just noticed

Comment: which version on Hazelcast do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed at later versions of Hazelcast by applying a schema check first and additional validations to make sure values make sense. Please upgrade, especially since there were serious issues fixed in later versions.